# Cannot use object of type EntityDrupalWrapper

Tags: 7, rules

I keep getting this error:

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type EntityDrupalWrapper as array in /sites/all/modules/rules/modules/php.eval.inc(146) : eval()'d code on line 29

when I use the below PHP code in rule

```
$t_exists = 0;
$etid = 0;
$vid =10;
$vname = 'emails';

$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$email_term = $wrapper->field_primary_email->value();

function customs_create_taxonomy_term($email_term, $vid) {
  $term = new stdClass();
  $term->name = $email_term;
  $term->vid = $vid;
  taxonomy_term_save($term);
  return $term->tid;
 }

function et_exist($vname, $email_term) {
$tid = NULL;
$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($vname);
$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary->vid);
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
      if ($term->name == $email_term) {
        $tid = $term->tid;
      }
    }
return $tid;
}

if ($wrapper->field_email_term_reference[0]->value()) {
foreach ($wrapper->field_email_term_reference->getIterator() as $index => $taxWrapper) {
  $taxWrapper->value()->name;
  $taxWrapper->value()->tid;
  $taxWrapper->value()->vid;
  $taxWrapper->value()->vocabulary_machine_name; 
if ($taxWrapper->value()->name == $email_term) {
$t_exists=1;
};
}

if (!$t_exists) {
$etid = et_exist($vname, $email_term);
If ($etid) {
$wrapper->field_email_term_reference[] = $etid;
} else {
$etid = customs_create_taxonomy_term($email_term, $vid);
$wrapper->field_email_term_reference[] = $etid;
}
$wrapper->save();
}; 
}
```

The line that seems to be causing the problem is:

```
if ($wrapper->field_email_term_reference[0]->value()) {
```

Please advice.

Comment: Which line is causing the problem?

Comment: The error mentions Line 29 as the cause

Comment: And what's on line 29? You must remember this is a Q+A site, not an excuse to forgo basic debugging!

Comment: I believe this is the line causing the error: if ($wrapper->field_email_term_reference[0]->value()) {   Sorry for the confusion, I am not a developer, do not know much about coding, trying to learn it with help from sites like these. I appreciate you trying to help me out

Comment: No apology necessary, we just need to be clear about the real source of the issue to a) make sure you get a valid answer without things devolving into a support session in the comments, and b) make sure people with a similar problem in future will be able to identify that this one is indeed similar to theirs :)

Answer (score 1):

The code is trying to access an `EntityDrupalWrapper` as if it was an `EntityValueWrapper`, which might suggest the field simply doesn't have a value for the entity that's throwing the error.

Since you're explicitly getting the first field item anyway, changing the `if` statement to something like this would probably fix it:

```
if ($wrapper->field_email_term_reference->value()) {
```

Comment: when I replace the code, it gives me the same error, but now eval()'d code on line 43, which is: $wrapper->field_email_term_reference[] = $etid;  I am truly lost. What does this error mean?

Comment: Possibly that the field was added after nodes of the type it was added to already existed. That sometimes throws entity metadata wrappers out of whack. I can only guess though, you need someone with access to the code and database to debug this really, there aren't many general pointers to give